# Why Mathematica does not Maximize when using parameter

Tags: equation-solving, mathematical-optimization

I have recently started using Mathematica and I have got a question using it. I would appreciate if one could help me figuring out how to handle it.
I have the following simple maximisation code

```
Assuming[a ∈ Real && b ∈ Real, ArgMax[a Sin[x] + b Cos[x] , 0 <= x < 2 π , x]]
```

and I expect the mathematica to solve it. This is indeed a very simple maximization and if I replace `a` and `b` with real numbers, I get the answer.

Could someone help me to make mathematica solve the parametric expression?

Comment: `Assuming[a ∈ Reals && b ∈ Reals && 0 <= x < 2 π, FullSimplify[Solve[D[a Sin[x] + b Cos[x], x] == 0, x]]]` works, tho.

Comment: thank you for the answer. however, this function is only part of another function with multiple variable. I am trying to figure out the problem in this simple case and apply it to a more general scenario

Comment: Well, for some reason, the symbolic optimization functions have trouble with transcendental objective functions. You may have to do some legwork of your own if you are sure that there is a closed-form solution to your problem.